# Logic for the model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, separation-of-concerns

The principles of MVC have got me thinking while making my Rails 4 app. I'm all for moving logic into the Model and sticking to the Fat Model principles
but just wondered what your thoughts would be on the following:

There exists a user initiated operation on my Payments table that changes the status of a payment. In order to cancel a payment, the payment must be already active.

I have chosen to use my Controller to establish that the status of the payment is active first before calling the method in the Model. My general approach is to let Controllers decide whether a call to the DB is required and only then will I call the method in the model to actually make the call.

Do you think I should let the Model make the decision on whether to update the status? For some reason this doesn't seem right to me.

It would be very interesting to hear some thoughts on this.

Comment: Actually, if you were implementing MVC, then the controllers would only be responsible for altering state of model layer and (rarely) current view instance. That's not a possible option in Rails. Unfortunately, only RoR's relation to MVC is in the "names for thing". It has replaced views with dumb templates and model layer with bunch of active records. This has caused both UI logic and significant part of model to be forced in "controllers".

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to put it in your model.

Reason:

1. Its the responsibility of the model. It should know when to cancel the payments.
2. DRY. you don't have to repeat the active check if you need the same behavior in a different place.
3. Easy to test since the whole logic is in single place.

`My general approach is to let Controllers decide whether a call to the DB is required and only then will I call the method in the model to actually make the call`

Model is not just to make DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

Business Logic goes to Model part in MVC. Role of Model is to contain data and business logic. Controller on the other hand is responsible to receive user input and decide what to do.